# Graphics Card Dilemma

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

Looking to update my graphics card and cannot decide between the Geforce GTS 450 or GTX 550Ti. I'm not really a gamer. Looking for easy install and stability more than anything. Anybody had any great success or problems with any of these cards? Any info would be most appreciated. Using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them are supported by nvidia

check [this external link](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-amd64-302.17-driver.html) from nvidia